# java.lang.NullPointerException and JSON

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

```
     // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "jSON");
                      loginErrorMsg.setText("");

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        UserFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addSubscriber( json.getString(KEY_RegIDSubscribers), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_Password), json_user.getString(KEY_Phone),json_user.getString(KEY_University),json_user.getString(KEY_Major), json.getString(KEY_GcmLocations));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I'm getting error starting the line of "try" and the error is java.lang.NullPointerException , also I'm getting java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject,I really don't know how to fix them, any help please?

Comment: please post the stack trace and the minimum functional code which is enclosing `try-catch`

Comment: If you post the stack we can help you some more, first guess though is that "json" might be null

Comment: @Sage how do I modify my question? I don't know how to modify my question :$

Comment: @lolo, elaborate answer. First tell us about which library you are using, what you intended to do, than paste the code with the function block which is enclosing it, with commenting the line you are getting null pointer exception at, etc.

Comment: @lolo There is an "edit" button under the tags you choose for your question, on the left between "share" and "flag".

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the stacktrace, but I'm guessing that `loginErrorMsg` is `null`. You may not initializing it, or passing a wrong viewId to `findViewById` method, wherever you retrieve the view.